# *.service run as user

Tags: systemd

I would like to run an application as a user, instead of root.

```
[Service]    
User=xy    
Group=z
```

works, but the application requires to bind to port 80 and 443. As I read online, ports below 1024 require root privileges. Thus, systemctl status .service returns and error with following log entry

`System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (13): Permission denied`

Comment: https://serverfault.com/a/917942/229499?

Comment: Read `man capabilities pam_cap capabilities.conf`. If you set user `xy:z` to have the `CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE` ("Bind a socket to Internet domain privileged ports (port numbers less than 1024") you won't have to be `root`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @muru there is a simple solution

```
[Service]
User=xy
Group=z
AmbientCapabilities=CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE
```

Comment: and `xy` is what? The Username? The user ID?

Comment: @xcy7e xy is the `username`. z equals the name of the `group`. E.g., in terms of root, it would be `User=root` and `Group=root`.